# In Emacs, how do I inspect what has been modified in a buffer (before saving and overwriting the file)?

Tags: files, emacs, diff

In Emacs, how do I inspect what has been modified in a buffer (before saving and overwriting the file)?

(In a sense, the requested action is an analog of `git status` and `git add -i` showing what has been modified, only the comparison should be done between the buffer contents (in Emacs's memory) and the file on disk.)

Sometime, I forget what has been modified in a buffer, and would like to call a command to remind me.

Comment: Some people might even like to "bind" this behavior with the saving or killing-the-buffer command: so that the diff is demonstrated before one decides whether to save or kill the buffer (that's similar to the interactive way of how `darcs record` works).

Comment: [The same question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7458/5165) at Emacs.SE has more interesting answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`diff-buffer-with-file`

I've just found it by looking through `files.el` where I felt there is such a command:

> View the differences between BUFFER and its associated file.

Comment: [The same question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7458/5165) at Emacs.SE has more interesting answers: `ediff-current-file` and `highlight-changes-mode`.